# Calling R function from C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to call R functions from C++ on Windows. I am using MinGW for compiling the program, but it throws error while compiling. Code (taken from Dirk) and compilation error are as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "RInside.h"  // for the embedded R via RInside


Rcpp::NumericMatrix createMatrix(const int n) {
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix M(n,n);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      M(i,j) = i*10+j;
    }
  }
  return(M);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const int mdim = 4;                         // let the matrices be 4 by 4
  SEXP ans;


  RInside R(argc, argv);                      // create an embedded R instance

  Rcpp::NumericMatrix M = createMatrix(mdim); // create and fill a sample data Matrix
  R["M"] = M;                                 // assign C++ matrix M to R's 'M' var

  std::string evalstr = "\
            cat('Running ls()\n'); print(ls());                    \
            cat('Showing M\n'); print(M);                          \
            cat('Showing colSums()\n'); Z <- colSums(M); print(Z); \
            Z";                     // returns Z

  ans = R.parseEval(evalstr);                 // eval the init string -- Z is now in ans

  Rcpp::NumericVector v(ans);                 // convert SEXP ans to a vector of doubles
  for (int i=0; i< v.size(); i++) {           // show the result
    std::cout << "In C++ element " << i << " is " << v[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -I "C:\ProgramFiles\R\R-2.14.0\library\RInside\include" -I "C:\Progra
mFiles\R\R-2.14.0\library\Rcpp\include" -I "C:\ProgramFiles\R\R-2.14.0\include"
RFunctions.cpp -o sh1.exe
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text+0x19a): und
efined reference to `RInside::RInside(int, char const* const*, bool)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text+0x1ee): und
efined reference to `RInside::operator[](std::string const&)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text+0x26d): und
efined reference to `RInside::parseEval(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text+0x35b): und
efined reference to `RInside::~RInside()'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text+0x3e1): und
efined reference to `RInside::~RInside()'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp7RO
bjectC2Ev[Rcpp::RObject::RObject()]+0x8): undefined reference to `vtable for Rcp
p::RObject'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp7RO
bjectC2Ev[Rcpp::RObject::RObject()]+0xd): undefined reference to `_imp__R_NilVal
ue'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN7RInside
5ProxyD1Ev[RInside::Proxy::~Proxy()]+0xd): undefined reference to `Rcpp::RObject
::~RObject()'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EED2Ev[Rcpp::Vector<14>::~Vector()]+0x16): undefined reference to `Rcpp
::RObject::~RObject()'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EED1Ev[Rcpp::Vector<14>::~Vector()]+0x16): undefined reference to `Rcpp
::RObject::~RObject()'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC1EP7SEXPREC[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(SEXPREC*)]+0x57): undefined ref
erence to `Rcpp::RObject::setSEXP(SEXPREC*)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC1EP7SEXPREC[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(SEXPREC*)]+0x66): undefined ref
erence to `Rcpp::RObject::~RObject()'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ma
trixILi14EEC1ERKiS3_[Rcpp::Matrix<14>::Matrix(int const&, int const&)]+0x2c): un
defined reference to `Rcpp::Dimension::Dimension(unsigned int const&, unsigned i
nt const&)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Rcpp6V
ectorILi14EE4sizeEv[Rcpp::Vector<14>::size() const]+0x10): undefined reference t
o `Rf_length'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6r_
castILi14EEEP7SEXPRECS2_[SEXPREC* Rcpp::r_cast<14>(SEXPREC*)]+0xd): undefined re
ference to `TYPEOF'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6r_
castILi14EEEP7SEXPRECS2_[SEXPREC* Rcpp::r_cast<14>(SEXPREC*)]+0x1d): undefined r
eference to `SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::r_true_cast<14>(SEXPREC*)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC2ERKNS_9DimensionE[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(Rcpp::Dimension const&)]
+0x46): undefined reference to `Rcpp::Dimension::prod() const'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC2ERKNS_9DimensionE[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(Rcpp::Dimension const&)]
+0x56): undefined reference to `Rf_allocVector'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC2ERKNS_9DimensionE[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(Rcpp::Dimension const&)]
+0x67): undefined reference to `Rcpp::RObject::setSEXP(SEXPREC*)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC2ERKNS_9DimensionE[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(Rcpp::Dimension const&)]
+0x7d): undefined reference to `Rcpp::Dimension::size() const'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC2ERKNS_9DimensionE[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(Rcpp::Dimension const&)]
+0xc9): undefined reference to `Rcpp::RObject::attr(std::string const&) const'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6Ve
ctorILi14EEC2ERKNS_9DimensionE[Rcpp::Vector<14>::Vector(Rcpp::Dimension const&)]
+0x13b): undefined reference to `Rcpp::RObject::~RObject()'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Rcpp11
Environment6assignINS_6MatrixILi14EEEEEbRKSsRKT_[bool Rcpp::Environment::assign<
Rcpp::Matrix<14> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocato
r<char> > const&, Rcpp::Matrix<14> const&) const]+0x23): undefined reference to
`Rcpp::Environment::assign(std::string const&, SEXPREC*) const'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp7RO
bject14AttributeProxyaSINS_9DimensionEEERS1_RKT_[Rcpp::RObject::AttributeProxy&
Rcpp::RObject::AttributeProxy::operator=<Rcpp::Dimension>(Rcpp::Dimension const&
)]+0x1c): undefined reference to `Rcpp::RObject::AttributeProxy::set(SEXPREC*) c
onst'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp8in
ternal13r_init_vectorILi14EEEvP7SEXPREC[void Rcpp::internal::r_init_vector<14>(S
EXPREC*)]+0xd): undefined reference to `double* Rcpp::internal::r_vector_start<1
4, double>(SEXPREC*)'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp8in
ternal13r_init_vectorILi14EEEvP7SEXPREC[void Rcpp::internal::r_init_vector<14>(S
EXPREC*)]+0x23): undefined reference to `Rf_length'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp8in
ternal21wrap_dispatch_unknownINS_9DimensionEEEP7SEXPRECRKT_NS_6traits17integral_
constantIbLb1EEE[SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch_unknown<Rcpp::Dimension>
(Rcpp::Dimension const&, Rcpp::traits::integral_constant<bool, true>)]+0xd): und
efined reference to `Rcpp::Dimension::operator SEXPREC*() const'
C:\Users\ksharma\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgMgFPS.o:RFunctions.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp6tr
aits14r_vector_cacheILi14EE6updateERKNS_6VectorILi14EEE[Rcpp::traits::r_vector_c
ache<14>::update(Rcpp::Vector<14> const&)]+0x15): undefined reference to `double
* Rcpp::internal::r_vector_start<14, double>(SEXPREC*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Jim is correct in his earlier answer, but there is more.

When using [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) , you also need to

1. include and link with [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) (which [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html)  depends upon) a
2. include and link with R (which both depends upon) as well as of course
3. [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html)'s own library

The easiest way of doing this is to simply use the Makefile from the `examples/standard` directory --- given that you copied the code of one of the examples, you should also copy the build instructions.

Lastly, and that is your biggest issue: RInside applications do not currently work on Windows, which is clearly documented on the [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) page.  It will build, but segfault on startup. Debugging help would be appreciated, this works on OS X and Linux.

Comment: Belated comment:  The "RInside on Windows" issue has been fixed for a while now; RInside works on Windows as it does on OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually linking in the R library (whatever that is).