# undefined references when using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to build an R package that is a wrapper around a C library (and which uses gsl) in Windows. I can transition to Linux, if necessary
For better or worse, I put the make commands for the C library in Makevars.in.
I used Rstudio's Rcpp skeleton feature to create the package. I have installed Rtools 3.3 and using R 3.3.1

and I included Rcpp and RcppGSL in LinkingTo field of DESCRIPTION. I am still getting undefined reference errors for the make command

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)   $(OBJECTS)  ../inst/libgraphm.a $(PKG_LIBS)
```

A few of the error are as follows

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RGraphM.dll tmp.def graphmatch_rcpp.o RcppExports.o -L../inst -lgraphm -LC:/tools/gsl/lib/x64 -lgsl -lgslcblas -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
#cd graphm && /usr/bin/make
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2   graphmatch_rcpp.o RcppExports.o  ../inst/libgraphm.a  -L../inst -lgraphm -LC:/tools/gsl/lib/x64 -lgsl -lgslcblas
graphmatch_rcpp.o: In function `PreserveStorage':
C:/Users/sadali/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/storage/PreserveStorage.h:10: undefined reference to `__imp_R_NilValue'
graphmatch_rcpp.o: In function `Vector':
C:/Users/sadali/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:58: undefined reference to `Rf_allocVector'
graphmatch_rcpp.o: In function `Rcpp_ReplaceObject':
```

The answer to this similar (in my eyes) question seems to be inapplicable
[Undefined reference errors when including Rcpp.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959000/undefined-reference-errors-when-including-rcpp-h#22959290)
as I am using LinkingTo and trying to create an R package

Edit: as the first answer suggested, I have tried building RcppZiggurat with the following Makevars.win :

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I. -I../inst/include  -IC:/tools/gsl/include 
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = $(LDFLAGS) -L../inst -L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/x64 $(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()")
```

I am getting these errors.

```
ziggurat.o:ziggurat.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_free'

ziggurat.o:ziggurat.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_free'
ziggurat.o:ziggurat.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_free'
ziggurat.o:ziggurat.cpp:(.text+0x1254): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_set'
```

Comment: the first salient lines from `graphmatch_rcpp.cpp` would be useful but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061254/calling-r-function-from-c-on-windows) may be your issue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the windows build running successfully using this template for `Makevars.win`
https://github.com/adalisan/RGraphM/blob/master/src/Makevars.win.gen

and this script creates the Makevars.win
https://github.com/adalisan/RGraphM/blob/master/configure.win

Once the pre-built gsl windows libraries have been put in the directory defined by  env. var `LIB_GSL`, both the compilation and linking steps worked.

One  small issue is that the zip file for the pre-built libraries [downloaded here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/goodies/multilib/) include there are two subdirectories for two sub-architectures (i386 and x64)
You should make sure that you link against the right version and that `-L"$(LIB_GSL)\lib\$(ARCH)"` argument in the linker calls evaluates to the right directory for the sub-arch.
Thanks to the creators of Rcpp and RcppGSL for making the packaging of gsl-based code easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding of how this works:

1. The `LinkingTo:` field of `DESCRIPTION` does not linking, despite its name.  It only helps for header files.  Which is why your package *compiled* but did not link.
2. You need linker instructions.  As has been said before, the [mvabund](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mvabund) and [RcppZiggurat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppZiggurat) packages both link to the GSL using a tool from [RcppGSL](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppGSL).

[RcppZiggurat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppZiggurat) in particular may be a good example to follow as it is small.  There is also [an entire example package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl/tree/master/inst/examples/RcppGSLExample) included in [RcppGSL](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppGSL) -- which we use as reference as well as in unit testing.

Comment: I am getting errors with RcppZiggurat building also. This is Makevars.win    PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I. -I../inst/include  -IC:/tools/gsl/include 
    ## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
    PKG_LIBS = $(LDFLAGS) -L../inst -L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/x64 $(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()")

Comment: You may want to debug it by looking at how the values are set and what values you are getting.  It works for the windows builds at CRAN -- maybe you just do not have the GSL root directory environment variable set.

Comment: The directories seem alright to me. This is the command that is run:    c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RcppZiggurat.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o ziggurat.o -L../inst -LC:/tools/gsl/lib/x64 -LC:/tools/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/i386 -lR

Comment: the gsl library files are in C:/tools/gsl/lib/x64 and is included in the linking call.